# SSL causing problems with rending of certain page elements

Tags: html, security, ssl, rendering

When the following page renders in HTTPS:// it causes the navigation bar to appear incorrectly, as well as the lines to not appear. From what I have read, it is from how style sheets are loaded in. However, from my research on here and Google, I could not discover how to correct the issue. I don't think I can use relative links as suggested on numerous posts on here. I think you can view all the source code you need, but if I need to post anything, please let me know. Thank in advance.

HTTPS version (Incorrect): https://propertytaxdfw.com/

HTTP Version (Correct):  http://propertytaxdfw.com/

New Test URLs with suggestion:
HTTPS version (Incorrect): https://propertytaxdfw.com/pay-invoicetest.html

HTTP Version (Incorrect):  http://propertytaxdfw.com/pay-invoicetest.html

Comment: Holy external sources batman! So your issue is all your external JS files are loaded using regular HTTP. You need to load everything over HTTPS. Notice the error on the lock in the URL bar (Chrome and Firefox do this for sure, I think IE does as well).  Secondly you should really consider how many external libraries you're loading I counted 30 before I gave up.

Comment: It is based in a template tool. I found the amount of code completely unneeded as well. I don't know what is actually needed though. So how can I load them over HTTPS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your JS loads over http whereas your html is based on https.

View Chrome Console for more information.

**"Mixed Content: The page at 'https://propertytaxdfw.com/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure stylesheet 'http://assets.neo.registeredsite.com/libs/jquery.fancyScroll/1.0/jquery.fancyScroll.css'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS."**

Moving your JS files to https and it should resolve

Comment: How do I change that? They are external right, so if you can't navigate to `https://assets.neo.registeredsite.com/libs/jquery.fancyScroll/1.0/jquery.fancyScroll.css',` is there anything I can do?

Comment: Download them and place them in your project directly, if they do not have https hosted files.

It should work.

Comment: Ok I will try that. A lot of files to download, but I will try.

Comment: google fonts already available on https. Others will need to be done manually.

Comment: Somewhat of a dumb question, how do I download the files? Do I just copy paste them?

Comment: Tried your solutions at a test link that I posted above in an edit to question. It still isn't working. Now I broke the http version as well. Did I mess something up?

Comment: Chrome console. Click every link that shows error. It will open file in new tab. Save it into ur project

Comment: I did that. Problem solved, now just have to get redirects set up, so it shows the rights versions.